# could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "database" (172.19.0.3) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I am trying to run Django tests on Gitlab CI but getting this error, Last week it was working perfectly but suddenly I am getting this error during test run

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
> Is the server running on host "database" (172.19.0.3) and accepting
> TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

**My gitlab-ci file is like this**

```
image: docker:latest
services:
  - docker:dind

variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2

test:
  stage: test
  image: tiangolo/docker-with-compose
  script:
    - docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml build
    - docker-compose run app python3 manage.py test
```

my docker-compose is like this:

```
version: '3'
volumes:
  postgresql_data:
services:
  database:
    image: postgres:12-alpine
    environment:
        - POSTGRES_DB=test
        - POSTGRES_USER=test
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123
        - POSTGRES_HOST=database
        - POSTGRES_PORT=5432
    volumes:
        - postgresql_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
        test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U $${POSTGRES_USER} -e \"SHOW DATABASES;\""]
        interval: 5s
        timeout: 5s
        retries: 5
    ports:
        - "5432"
    restart: on-failure

  app:
    container_name: proj
    hostname: proj
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: sampleproject
    command: >
      bash -c "
        python3 manage.py migrate  &&
        python3 manage.py wait_for_db  &&
        gunicorn sampleproject.wsgi:application -c ./gunicorn.py
      "
    env_file: .env
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
        - .:/srv/app
    depends_on:
       - database
       - redis
```

So why its refusing connection? I don't have any idea and it was working last week.

Comment: Do you need to `wait_for_db` before you `migrate`?  Is the database container in fact starting up?

Comment: @DavidMaze  not sure sir . How I can check on gitlb-ci either container is up or not ? As I am just running tests ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66232137/github-action-docker-database-migration-fail

Answer (score 1):

Unsure if it would help in your case but I was getting the same issue with docker-compose. What solved it for me was explicitly specifying the hostname for postgres.

```
services:
  database:
    image: postgres:12-alpine
    hostname: database
    environment:
        - POSTGRES_DB=test
        - POSTGRES_USER=test
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123
        - POSTGRES_HOST=database
        - POSTGRES_PORT=5432

    ...
```

Answer (score -1):

Could you do a `docker container ls` and check if the container name of the database is in fact, "database"?
You've skipped setting the `container_name` for that container, and it may be so that docker isn't creating it with the default name of the service, i.e. "database", thus the DNS isn't able to find it under that name in the network.

Comment: its working fine on local. but doing issue on Gitlab-CI

Comment: how I can check this on gitlab ? as my service for db is  "database"  so I am using this in db

Answer (score -3):

Reboot the server. I encounter similar errors on Mac and Linux from time to time when I run more than one container that use postgres.

Comment: How I can reboot gitlab-CI ?